# In IE, weird issue with QueryString having "copy" as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, query-string, internet-explorer-11

I am facing a weird issue related to querystring in IE11.

I have an anchor tag which has href. One of the parameters passed in the querystring is the word "copy" as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

In Chrome, it works perfectly fine.

In IE, when I try to access the querystring, I find that it is changed to something else as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

This works fine if I change that parameter to something else e.g. "cid".

Can someone please help me out to figure out what is happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%uxxxx` is a nonstandard html encoding for unicode characters.  `%3d` is a standard html encoding for the `=` character.   Internet explorer is treating "&copy" as a character entity, even though it's lacking the trailing semicolon.  In order to fix this, replace the original ampersand with its html entity representation.

```
qid=13412&amp;copy=true
```

Comment: The solution is working fine but shouldn't it be raised as an issue with IE ?

Comment: I suppose so.  First check if it affects the most recent version.  If so you can file a bug report.